# What Is The Java Libraries' Source File Algorithm For Math.tan(x)?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I've been looking for the Java Math library source code for tan(x).
It's not in my JDK 1.8_60 folder.

I ask here now as I am curious about the algorithm/series that is used within the Math.tan(x) method.

Using the MacLaurin series for tan(x) demands a lot of odd terms to get decent precision up to 60 degrees. Using MacLaurin series' for Sin(x) and Cos(x) and then dividing runs out of precision too as 90 degrees is approached.

Comment: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Math.java#Math.tan%28double%29

Comment: @SLaks and if you look there, you'll see that it is implemented in native code, so there's no Java implementation there to see...

Comment: @Jesper : Was wondering what they meant by 'native' . . . Looks like I'll have to check out A & S or Numerical Recipes.

Comment: Nothing but the MacLaurin expansion for tan(x) in A & S. Just got 2 downvotes ... I assume for asking a question that no one had a ready answer to.

Comment: On most computers it will use the FPU tan command. The StrictMath implementation is for situations where no FPU is present.

Comment: What or where do I find code for FPU tan(x) ? I found this [link](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap10.htm#fptan) but it's not clear what algorithm is being used in the assembler code.

Comment: There is just this one instruction. Load the argument on the FPU stack, execute the `FPTAN` instruction, store the resulting top of the stack to the memory location of the result. The microcode that is executed inside the FPU is usually a business secret of the processor manufacturer.

Comment: Okay. We can guess the algo by now . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.tan()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#tan-double-) just calls [`StrictMath.tan()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#tan-double-), which is a *native* method.

Source code for Java can be found at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/

- Java 8 source for [`Math.tan()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l157)
- Java 8 source for [`StrictMath.tan()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/StrictMath.java#l122)
- C source for [`StrictMath` methods](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src)

  - The [`s_tan.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/s_tan.c#l59) file is the implementation of `StrictMath.tan()`. It calls the `__kernel_tan()` function in [`k_tan.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/k_tan.c#l86).

Comment: The last link suggests that tan(x) is evaluated via a MacLaurin of degree 27 for most values. I see some differences in the higher order coefficients that are quoted in that link and those I used. So I better check these . . . Many thanks for link.

Comment: The coefficients used by the Math.tan(x) method are:
T[] =  {

  3.33333333333334091986e-01,

  1.33333333333201242699e-01,

  5.39682539762260521377e-02, 

  2.18694882948595424599e-02, 

  8.86323982359930005737e-03,

  3.59207910759131235356e-03,

  1.45620945432529025516e-03, 

  5.88041240820264096874e-04,

  2.46463134818469906812e-04,

  7.81794442939557092300e-05, 

  7.14072491382608190305e-05,

 -1.85586374855275456654e-05, 

  2.59073051863633712884e-05, 

};  These are imprecise for the high orders. One is the wrong sign. Maybe a fitted polynomial ?

Comment: @Trunk: Good math programmers rarely use Maclaurin series directly. It is common to use them to get a working answer to full precision then use [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) or something similar to reduce the number of terms in the calculated polynomial. The idea is to trade bad precision for large parameter values and excellent precision for small values in Maclaurin series for a more even precision among all values and fewer terms.

Comment: Yeah, it figures using a fitted finite polynomial instead of the  slow-converging MacLaurin series. Seems like our pocket calculators do the same. Yet curious how Abramovitz & Stegun never alluded to that. President Roosevelt was short-changed on that one. Hey - whaddya mean "good" programmers ? Informed or sneaky-eyed programmers you mean !

Answer (score 1):

Usually, implementations will reduce the argument towards zero using trigonometric identities like

```
tan(a+b)= ( tan(a)+tan(b) ) / (1-tan(a)*tan(b) )
```

which for `b=45°` gives

```
tan(a+45°) = ( 1+tan(a) ) / ( 1-tan(a) )
```

Further reductions are possible this way if one hard-codes the tangent values for 30° or 15°.

One can also use this identity for a half-angle relation,

```
tan(a) = 2*tan(a/2) / ( 1-tan(a/2)^2 )
```

which also allows to reduce the angle.

With first the restriction to [-45°, 45°] and then 3 angle halvings one would reach the range [-6°, 6°] where already a lower degree Taylor polynomial will give sufficiently good approximations.

Comment: Yes. Precise tan data is around longer than computers so methods like this must have been in use by trigonometricians.

Comment: The problem with using these 2 expressions is that the precision of the tan(x+45) is inversely proportional to a term, (1 - tan(x))^2 . . .  And this term goes skyward as x approaches 45 . . .

Comment: Then use tan(45°+x)=1/tan(45°-x), or use the usual half-angle formulas.

Comment: Similar problem with the precisions using the half-angle or 45 reflection. It's great for small x but the number of terms needed in the tan(x/2) or tan(45-x) needs to be scaled up to achieve acceptable tan(x) or tan(45+x) precision as x approaches 90 or 45 respectively.

Comment: I see not where your problem with precision resp. the relative error is. Close to pi/2 you can use tan(x)=1/tan(pi/2-x). This is as exact as (pi/2-x) is, i.e., the dominant error is the truncation error in that difference, and that error is unavoidable.

Comment: Sure with RELATIVE precision but I was looking at ABSOLUTE precision and taking it that tan45 could be got at 10^-7. Relative precision would look bad for x > 80 degrees. So it seems that the finite series approach is the most useful.